# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult' to 'RegLog.Controllers.IActionResult'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I would like to ask for help since I am creating a filter searchbox for my ASP.net MVC. I followed this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-2.2 but it had an error on this code.

```
public async Task <IActionResult> Index(string searchString)
    {
        using (DBModelEntities dbModel = new DBModelEntities())
        {
            ViewData["CurrentFilter"] = searchString;

            var products = (from p in dbModel.Products
                            select p);
            if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                products.Where(p => p.productName.Contains(searchString));
            }

            return View(await products.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync());//it had the error which states that Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult' to 'RegLog.Controllers.IActionResult'
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which MVC version you're currently using? Make sure you're referenced and used `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` instead of `System.Web.Mvc` to return `ViewResult` from `IActionResult`.

Comment: Where did `RegLog.Controllers.IActionResult` come from? Did you create your own `IActionResult` interfade? Or used one from a library? In any case the error is clear - somehow the `RegLog.Controllers` namespace was added to your controller with a `using` statement and the compiler thinks the `IActionResult` you specified comes from that namespace. The solution is to *remove* that `using` statement. You should probably remove that class. Having classes that share the same name as a .NET infrastructure class can only lead to problems

Comment: THe code has another problem - it's trying to load *all* products, not just those that contain the search string. `products.Where` creates a new Queryable, it doesn't modify the existing one

Comment: @JimboDelfin Third problem, as others mentioned : `System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult` isn't part of ASP.NET Core, it's part of the Full framework. I suspect you didn't start the tutorial from the [Get Started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-2.2) page. The ASP.NET Core project templates add the correct packages that provide both IActionResult and ActionResult

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think I created my own IActionResult. I am pretty new in MVC so I am very sorry. How can I remove that sir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The import `RegLog.Controllers` is wrong. This package is coming from another framework. Make sure to use the import `using System.Web.Mvc;` or `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;` from the tutorial.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.actionresult?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2

Comment: I think i added it. How can I remove it sir? Pretty new in MVC

Comment: Just search for `RegLog.Controllers` in your file and delete the line containing the string. The line should look something like `using RegLog.Controllers;`