# cannot implicitly convert type System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult to Microsoft.Aspnetcore.mvc.Iactionresult

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Im trying to implement a search function on a page using the following code.
[HttpGet]

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string Empsearch)
    {
        ViewData["Getcontactdetails"] = Empsearch;

        var empquery = from x in db.Contacts select x;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Empsearch))
        {
            empquery=empquery.Where(x=>x.fname.Contains(Empsearch) || x.email.Contains(Empsearch)); 
        }
        return View(await empquery.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync());
    }
```

however im a getting the error cannot implicitly convert type System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult to Microsoft.Aspnetcore.mvc.Iactionresult

i dont really understand what is wrong

Comment: This question can be useful. https://stackoverflow.com/q/55179247/6895130

Comment: Does `(IActionResult)return View(await empquery.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync());` help?

Comment: _"i dont really understand what is wrong"_ - the problem is **you're mixing old-school 2000s ASP.NET with modern 2020s ASP.NET Core** - they're massively incompatible and normally this can't even happen because ASP.NET Core is now strictly .NET Core 3.1+ while `System.Web` ASP.NET  is only available on .NET Framework 4.x (vintage 2010) - _yikes_.

Comment: ...though the exception is ASP.NET Core 1.x and 2.x, which _could_ run on .NET Framework 4.x

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `IActionResult` with `.Net Framework`, then you have to change the code below and remove the `.Net Core` reference.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string Empsearch){
}
```